# Sending array over MPI point to point communication

Tags: c, mpi

Hi I am trying to send the edges of a 2-dim array over point to point communcation with MPI.

```
struct image {
    /* image data block */
    double **data; //2dim array

    /* boundaries */
    double *top;
    double *bot;
    double *left;
    double *right;

    /* dimensions */
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Every node has it's own image (same width and height) and the boundaries where the exchanged data should be received. Every node allready knows where to send/receve the data. The receive-buffers(top, bot, left, right) are already allocated.
What doesn't work is that I always get a Segmentation fault during the exchage process.

Here is my critical method:

```
void MPI_stencil_p_to_p(struct image *img, int *neighbours, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (neighbours[i] != MPI_PROC_NULL){
            count+=2;
        }
    }
    MPI_Status status[count];
    MPI_Request req[count];
    int count_tmp = count;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (neighbours[i] != MPI_PROC_NULL){
            count_tmp--;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("%d: %d\n", ra, neighbours[i]);
                printf("works %d\n", ra);
                MPI_Isend(img->data[0], img->width, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                count_tmp--;
                MPI_Irecv(&img->top, img->width, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                continue;
            } else if (i == 2)
            {
                printf("%d: %d\n", ra, neighbours[i]);
                int len = img->height-1;
                MPI_Isend(img->data[len], img->width, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                count_tmp--;
                MPI_Irecv(&img->bot, img->width, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                continue;
            }

            MPI_Datatype col;
            MPI_Type_vector(img->height, 1, img->width, MPI_DOUBLE, &col);
            MPI_Type_commit(&col);

            if (i == 1)
            {
                printf("%d: %d\n", ra, neighbours[i]);
                MPI_Isend(&img->data[0][0], 1, col, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                count_tmp--;
                MPI_Irecv(&img->right, img->height, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
            } else
            {
                printf("%d: %d\n", ra, neighbours[i]);
                int len = img->width-1;
                MPI_Isend(&img->data[0][len], 1, col, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
                count_tmp--;
                MPI_Irecv(&img->left, img->height, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[i], TAG, comm, &req[count_tmp]);
            }
            MPI_Type_free(&col);
        }
    }
    if (MPI_Waitall(count, req, status) != MPI_SUCCESS)
        error_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "MPI_Waitall");
}
```

Thank's for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly where the segfault is occurring, I'm just guess where the error is. However, every time someone asks a question like this, it's because they've constructed a 2D array using double pointers and they don't have a densely packed matrix. MPI expects to send/receive contiguous data, so if you try to send multiple rows of a matrix allocated like this:

```
double **data;
data = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) data[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * m);
```

you'll run into a problem because `data[0][m-1]` and `data[1][0]` are not necessarily in consecutive locations in memory.

Instead, when sending matrices in MPI, you either need to allocate them as one-dimensional arrays and do the extra math or send each row individually.